# C Programming: declaring string and assignment

Tags: c, string, variables

```
int main(){
   char inputType[5] = "hello you"; //a string 
   char *word[5]; //a string that will contain 4 character + the null
   word = get_word(inputType);
   return 0;
}
char *get_word(char inputType[]){ //inputType is a string
    char *array[2]; //an array that will store ["hello", "you"]
    // got correct code to make it ["hello", "you"]
    return array[1] //want to return "you"
}
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: word = get_word (inputType) assingment to expression with array Type------------------------------
```

Questions:

1. Does char inputType[5] declare a string?
2. Difference between char `*word[5]` vs `inputType[5]`
3. The reason of the error message.

Comment: what is `get_word()`?

Comment: also in `char inputType[5] = "hello you";` you have assigned more than 5 characters here.

Comment: get_word is the function

Comment: Ok, because first you wrote `*word()` Thanks for editing

Comment: `get_word()` returns a character while `word` is a string. So you can run: `word = get_word(inputType);` because the types are incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong

```
char inputType[5] = "hello you";
```

`hello you` is 9 characters long and you also need the null terminator so you need...

```
char inputType[10] = "hello you";
```

This is wrong because the comment is wrong

```
char *word[5]; //a string that will contain 4 character + the null
```

`char *word[5]` is not a C string, it's an array of 5 pointers to C strings that have not yet been allocated.

Comment: so is char*word[5] represented as [pointer1 to char, pointer 2 to char, pointer 3 to char, pointer 4 to char, pointer 5 to char]?

Comment: When you use `type_t id[100];` you are asking for 100 items of type_t and they're declared on the stack. This, `char *word[5];` declares 5 items ie 5 pointers to strings, note, to be clear a valid C string must have a Null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes it declares a char array of size 5 (including the NUL character)where you are storing more than 5 characters.
2. First one is array of `char*` and second one array `char`s.
3. Yes char*word[5] is not what you are thinking..unless you allocate memory it can just hold addresses of memory locations where characters are stored.

   char* arr[5]

   ```
         |
   ---------------------------------- ~~
   |             |        |         |
   | char*       |        |         |
   ---------------------------------- ~~
       arr[0]      arr[1]    arr[2]
   ```

### Few things that you can do

1. you are basically initializing the char array. So do this
   `char inputType[]= "Hello You";`
2. The **error message** is basically shown due to this line
   `word = get_word(inputType);`
   well what you are doing? You are assigning `char*` to an array variable which is supposed to contain `char*`-s

So that will be `word[0]=get_word()....`

3. Don't forget to keep a place for NUL terminator at the end of char array.

Comment: could I fix the error by (1)char word[5] = word(inputType)...Does my function char *word return a string?

Comment: pointer to a string. Now you can copy it or do whatever (remember this is possible if you return pointer to an dynamically allocated memory or static variables).

Comment: @amay20.: Hope this helps...check my answer.